# How to aggregate results in a collection in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working on a cypher query (Neo4j v2.1.3) where I need to aggregate the results from several collections for use in a separate analysis. I am starting with the following query where I am returning all the Person nodes between the ones we are interested in and a specific Host.

```
MATCH (person:person), (host:person {name:'Host'}),
p = shortestPath((person)-[*]-(host))
WHERE person.name IN ['Steve','Jane']
RETURN collect(extract(n IN nodes(p)| n.name))
```

This returns a collection that includes the results from both person.name values in my WHERE condition.

```
Bob, Jordan, John, Jane, Lisa, Robert, John, Bob, John, Lisa, Bob, Lisa
```

What I want is to aggregate the values and list a count of how many each was listed ordered by descending count.

```
Bob, 3
John, 3
Lisa, 3
Robert, 1
Jordan, 1
Jane, 1
```

How can I add to my query to do this in one cypher statement?

**UPDATE:** 
From @Luanne's answer, I had to make an adjustment to get it to work correctly.

```
MATCH (person:person), (host:person {name:'Host'}),
p = shortestPath((person)-[*]-(host))
WHERE person.name IN ['Steve','Jane']
WITH collect(extract(n IN nodes(p)| n.name)) as nameList 
UNWIND nameList AS name
UNWIND name as ind_name
WITH ind_name, count(*) AS count
RETURN ind_name,count
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [unwind](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-unwind.html) your collection to count names:

```
MATCH (person:person), (host:person {name:'Host'}),
p = shortestPath((person)-[*]-(host))
WHERE person.name IN ['Steve','Jane']
with collect(extract(n IN nodes(p)| n.name)) as nameList 
unwind nameList AS name
WITH name, count(*) AS count
RETURN name,count
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: This returns each nameList with a count of 1. So...Bob, Jordan, John, Jane, Lisa, Robert   1   John, Bob, John, Lisa, Bob, Lisa    1

Comment: I needed to take the UNWIND one step in your example one step further. I will add that update to my question.

Comment: as an additional question, how could I limit the RETURN rows to only show those that have a count > 1?

Comment: Just add a where count>1 before the return: WITH name, count(*) as count where count>1 return name,count order by count desc